# Single word for building the future

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Can we come up with a single English word that conveys the idea of building a better future?
Preferably a single word, or otherwise two words with a hyphen. It is about building a better future for the world, or community, and therefore also building on your own future. Improving life as it is today. I have worked with synonyms a lot, narrowing down options such as future changemaker; life-changing; forward-looking;originators; forward-driven. I'm missing the active, practical element of building, improving, or contributing.

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: Thank you, the word is not meant to be used in a sentence. It's more of a title or a header. But I can make one up if it is helpful.

Comment: Future-building?

Comment: Students learn to solve the world's current issues and to contribute to building a future for all.

Comment: Well, future-building is certainly logical.

Comment: What about future makers?

Comment: Take *leaps and bounds* for example: *The atomic bomb changed our future by leaps and bounds.* Or any such word or phrase: They *forged ahead* with more megatons to everyone's…what? The *evolution* of nuclear power… I would narrow the scope of innovation…to building dog parks or something like that; diversifying 4H or whatever.

Comment: Would "innovating" work?

Comment: yes, it would, thank you. And I think I can get away with a phrase after all, instead of a single word, if it is really good.

Comment: I think we ***must*** have a more clearly-defined target context. It's unclear whether the sought term should even be an *adjective, adverb, noun,* or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

it's a good question and I think we need such a word!

**Progressive** perhaps isn't really inspiring enough but it's the best I've been able to come up with so far.

Progressive - meaning, forward thinking, modern, and concerned with progress.  Someone who is interested in social reform.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/progressive

Comment: Progressive is an adjective, and as such it seems to me not a complete answer. It might also be too politically charged to be neutral enough to feel inclusive.

Comment: that it is an adjective is not a problem. I would definitely need something inclusive though. Thanks to everyone who contributed.

Comment: You're welcome. How about visionary? Or Utopian...

Comment: I thought of that too. You can't very well include people in something they're against. We also have a *progressive* tax rate and *conservative* attire. Parties don't own words.